# Can WebView be used inside a service?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-service

I have an app that checks a specific website every one minute to see if it finds whatever I am looking for, then notifies me (Plays Sound) whenever the item is found. I followed this tut to make my app run in the background, but I noticed it complains about the WebView.

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

If it's not possible to use a WebView inside a service, what are my alternatives to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Why do you even *have* a `WebView`? What role is the `WebView` playing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Using WebView outside an Activity context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865035/android-using-webview-outside-an-activity-context)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, a `WebView` should not be used inside a service, and it really doesn't make sense to, anyway. If you're loading your `WebView` with the intention of scraping the html contained in it, you might as well just run an HttpGet request, like this --

```
public static String readFromUrl( String url ) {
    String result = null;

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet( url ); 

    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = client.execute( get );
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader( is ) );
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null )
                    sb.append( line + "\n" );
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                Log.e( "readFromUrl", e.getMessage() );
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch ( IOException e ) {
                    Log.e( "readFromUrl", e.getMessage() );
                }
            }

            result = sb.toString();
            is.close();
        }


    } catch( Exception e ) {
        Log.e( "readFromUrl", e.getMessage() );
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: "a WebView can not be used inside a service" -- actually, that's not strictly true, though in this case your solution is what is appropriate, most likely. Though I would recommend `Log.e()` instead of `printStackTrace()`, and Google recommends `HttpUrlConnection` over HttpClient.

Comment: @CommonsWare, changed my "can" to "should" and replaced the Log.e. I'm aware of Google's preference for HttpUrlConnection, but for clarity's sake, I prefer HttpClient. Old habits.

Comment: @323go How about keeping the sesstion or cookies or ...? for example,I login to website so if I use your solution,How should I make request for authorized page?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a service runs in the background and should not able able to display any UI.

But you can have an Activity (a UI process) passed its context to a service using PendingIntent.getService(context, GET_ADSERVICE_REQUEST_CODE, ...).  Then when the service is ready to display, the lines below should launch browser (or you owner app with appropriate Intent Filter for own WebView) to display the web content.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i,
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use a static Webview from another activity of your project.
for example:
MainActivity.web2.loadUrl ( "" );
in your Service.