# How to preload Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, startactivityforresult

My aar has an Activity, and when I call the API, it creates an Activity every time.

also use the startActivityForResult function to get a response from the Activity.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    Intent myActivity= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myActivity.class);
    myActivityOption option = new myActivityOption();

    option.setType(2);
    myActivity.putExtra("myActivityOption", option);

    startActivityForResult(myActivity, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

When MyActivity is created, it takes 2-3 seconds to draw a lot of images.

I want to make the delay occur only once.

I would like to be able to create an Activity without delays after initial init in the same form as class.

I'm sorry I missed my English.

Comment: possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746448/preload-activity-in-android?lq=1)

Comment: I'll try. Thank you. :)

Comment: if you have a lot of images consider to load them in a async task under a HeadlessFragment. Then you can store your image in a static list (can be an idea)