# Window type can not be changed after the window is added

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make custom lock screen. So, there I need not to allow user to press Home Button. In the beginning I write

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.lock_screen);

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

Then I override OnKeyDown

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, android.view.KeyEvent event) {

if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)||(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)||(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)||(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)) {
    //this is where I can do my stuff
    return true; //because I handled the event
}
if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)){

    return true;
}

return false;

}
```

Here I override onAttacheToWindow

```
 @Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

But it's giving me error IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added. Where is my mistake?

How can I handle Home Button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "good" way to handle the home button to "do nothing". You really only have two options which may or may not be good enough for you:

1. Create your own home launcher. Users must select your app as their home launcher.
2. You could also create a `Service` where you add a view to your window and it gets plastered on top of everything else. See my previous answer here with "displaying" a webview in a Service: [Android: Using WebView outside an Activity context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865035/android-using-webview-outside-an-activity-context/18989695#18989695). You will need to modify `params` to fill the screen and also fix `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` to use the right flags to allow clicks. This won't actually block the home button but it will basically disable it's functionality. Lastly, this might not work on Android 5.0+ as the Status bar's dropdown may overlay your window.