# How to use WebView in an IntentService?

Tags: android, webview, intentservice

I'm in the same situation with [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865035/android-using-webview-outside-an-activity-context). I need to use a `WebView` in an `IntentService`. To summarize:

- I need to use JavaScript and manage cookies, therefore easiest way to have these available is to use some kind of a GUI-less browser.
- There are no GUI-less web browser available for Android, so I have to find a way to use `WebView` or find a way to emulate a browser.
- I want to use a `WebView` instance which can only run on an UI thread.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to serialize the `context` of my `activity` so I can use this `context` to create my `WebView`?
- How to use Androids [ContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) class to emulate an activity?

Any other thoughts that are not mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865035/android-using-webview-outside-an-activity-context)? Some food for thought:
[Link1](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=359#c7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are no GUI-less web browser available for Android

While I have not tried it recently, `WebView` at least used to have no particular requirement for displaying its UI. I used `WebView` from within a `Service`, in my case for a JavaScript interpreter (back before we had better options for that).

Now, an `IntentService` is not a good choice. `WebView` is largely asynchronous, and `IntentService` will destroy itself before `WebView` gets a chance to do its work. Use a regular `Service`, where you control the `Service` lifetime, so you can call `stopSelf()` only when you are ready to do so.

> I want to use a WebView instance which can only run on an UI thread.

The relationship between `WebView` and threads is complicated. But, back when I last tried it, IIRC, a `WebView` that is not actually appearing on the screen did not need the main application thread. But, as I noted, `WebView` does most of its work asynchronously. You may find that you do not need a background thread of your own.

> Is there a way to serialize the context of my activity so I can use this context to create my WebView?

No, nor would it address any of your concerns.

> How to use Androids ContextWrapper class to emulate an activity?

That is not possible, nor would it address any of your concerns.

Comment: Hi, I'm using a slightly modified (trimmed to work without alarmreciever) version of your `WakefulIntentService`. I also created a `SyncBrowse` class that I initialize with an instance of `WebView`, which handles the asynchronous behavior of the `WebView`. This class waits until my JS is executed or the page-load is complete using a `JavaScriptInferance` and `.wait()` `.notify()`. Should I be concerned that I make my WakefulIntentService wait so long? FYI this app will not be used by large masses, just couple of people for couple of hours per day with ~1hr inbetween ServiceAlarms.

Comment: @cozkul: "Should I be concerned that I make my WakefulIntentService wait so long?" -- that is not what `WakefulIntentService`, or `IntentService` itself, was designed for. Use a regular `Service`, so you can control the threads and the service lifetime.

Comment: Hi again. I moved everything over to a `Service`. It is not possible to initialize a `WebView` with a `Service` context. When I declare a `static public Context` in one of my activities and use this to initialize my `WebView` at least it initializes, but still when you give webView.loadUrl() command the app crashes. Do you have any idea to make this work?

Comment: @cozkul: "It is not possible to initialize a WebView with a Service context" -- as I wrote, it used to work. However, it has been quite some time since I tried it. What specific problem did you encounter? 'Do you have any idea to make this work?" -- I suggest that you open a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you provide your code, your stack traces, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll create a new question with better explanation and provide code tomorrow. I found out that when you use a static context everything works but you must call loadUrl on the main UI thread.