# How to ensure network connectivity for an Android app on standby?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am currently writing an Android application which uses a webview and webrtc to transmit an Audio stream. The problem, at least on my mobile phone the connection is cut after a few minutes after the screen is turned off.

I already acquired a CPU lock and a wifi lock (verified with [isHeld](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html#isHeld())), but it does not make any difference.

The application is also available as a [web application](https://app.gonimo.com): Here it seems to work as expected and the connection stays alive.

I already checked the wifi settings: It is set to always on.

Any pointers/ideas greatly appreciated. The application is open source so I am happy to share any code, if that helps in any way. Lock grabbing is done with this:

```
private void grabWakeLock() {
  PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
  wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                                               "MyWakelockTag");
  wakeLock.acquire();
  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
  wifiLock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "gonimo-wifi-lock");
  wifiLock.acquire();
}
```

I have the following permissions in my Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Many thanks in advance!

### Update:

[Android Doze](https://www.androidauthority.com/get-your-apps-ready-to-doze-715022/) seems to be the reason for this behaviour. Manually triggering Doze, results in the same behaviour. Also

```
    return pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName);
```

is returning false, so network will be turned off for the app! The problem: the whitelist as described in the [article](https://www.androidauthority.com/get-your-apps-ready-to-doze-715022/) does not seem to exist on my phone. I can't find it in settings and doing:

```
    Intent intentBattery = new  Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    intentBattery.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + "org.gonimo.gonimo"));
    startActivity(intentBattery);
```

results in an Exception that the Activity cannot be found.

Comment: Almost forgot: Android version: 7.0, EMUI Version: 5.0.1 (It is a Huawei Nova)

Comment: Please add what is shown in the log when 'the connection is cut'.

Comment: how did you start your audio streaming service?

Comment: have you tried `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` ?

Comment: I am starting the audio streaming service via WebRTC in the WebView.

Comment: I haven't tried getWindow() ...., I will look into this function. Although it is not what I want. I want the display to go off, I just want the stream to stay alive.

Comment: Logs: http://lpaste.net/362689
I don't know how I missed that, there are a whole bunch of those messages:

    chromium: [INFO:socket_host_udp.cc(403)] sendto() has failed twice     returning a  transient error net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED. Dropping the packet.

The disconnect happened around: 14:12:00 .

Comment: also interesting in the logs: 
02-20 14:12:29.182 17523 17523 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(252)] "WebSocket connection to 'wss://b00.alpha.gonimo.com/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT", source:  (252)
02-20 14:12:29.183 17523 17538 D HaskellActivity: [INFO:CONSOLE(252)] "WebSocket connection to 'wss://b00.alpha.gonimo.com/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT", source:  (252)
02-20 14:12:29.193 17523 17538 D HaskellActivity: WebSocket got closed! (JS event)

hmmm

Comment: It seems different devices have different solutions according to this [forum](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/599333-wifi-turning-goes-sleep-despite-settings-keep.html). Solutions include turning off battery optimization, keep-alive-apps, rebooting,toggling *"Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep"*, and keeping the charger plugged in !

Comment: Regarding your last update: you should use `Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an "Android, please don't kill my long running background operation" recipe

1. Move your stream transmission code into a [service running in foreground](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)
2. [Keep the CPU running](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu) (if needed)
3. Make sure, that your app is excluded from the doze mode (because the user has to do this for you, you have to explain the reason in a nice overlay, before asking for it)

Checking:

```
PowerManager powerManager =
     (PowerManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.POWER_SERVICE);

powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getActivity().getPackageName());
```

Asking for the white-listing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Don't see that as encouragement to use this as general approach, There are only a few use cases that legitimize this procedure.**

Comment: Many thanks! Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS did the trick. Unfortunately the user experience sucks a lot, but at least it works. 

The service running in foreground solution, is I believe not really applicable, as the streaming service is part of the WebView and can't be a service - is that correct?

Comment: OMG somebody [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865035/android-using-webview-outside-an-activity-context) this madness already :) But  I would really encourage you to solve this by a native implementation.

Comment: I actually found that one already during my research, but I misunderstood a few things. I believe having an Activity that is a foreground service is no problem at all, so this should solve my problem. I will give it a try! Thank you very much for your help!

I'd like to avoid a native implementation, because Android is just one of our target platforms and rewriting all of that for Android would be quite a bunch of work. ;-)